# No data coming in resultset

Tags: java, resultset

I have below code:

```
string query = select COUNT(*) from  TRACKER where TYPE = ? and LAST_MODIFIED_TIME > LAST_RETREIVED_TIME;
prepStmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            prepStmt.setString(1, "xml");

            resultset = prepStmt.executeQuery();

            resultset.next();   
            int rowcount = resultset.getInt("COUNT(*)");
```

In database i have 1 row for the above query but in code i am getting rowcount= 0.
any help?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886462/get-row-count-of-a-resultset-in-java

Comment: db is oracle. i checked there , i am getting 1 as output

Comment: Try to give ALIAS to your `COUNT(*)` column and then check. `select COUNT(*) res from ... ` and use `int rowcount = resultset.getInt("res");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving an alias to the `count(*)` :

```
String query = "select COUNT(*) as count from  TRACKER where TYPE = ?"+
               " and LAST_MODIFIED_TIME > LAST_RETREIVED_TIME";
prepStmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
prepStmt.setString(1, "xml");
resultset = prepStmt.executeQuery();
resultset.next();   
int rowcount = resultset.getInt("count");
```