# cached Row set populate method not working for sqlserver database

Tags: java, cachedrowset

I wrote following code

```
public JSONObject getListByUserSQLQuery(JSONObject preparedQuery,final int jsonType,final Map<Object, Object>mMap,final JSONObject pagination)
            throws Exception {
            SqlParameterSource parameterSource=getMapFromParam(preparedQuery);
            final CachedRowSet cachedRowSet=new CachedRowSetImpl();
            System.out.println(pagination);
            Object obj=namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(preparedQuery.getString("query"), parameterSource, new ResultSetExtractor<Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,
                        DataAccessException {
                    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                    if(pagination.has("_LIMIT_")){
                        cachedRowSet.setPageSize(pagination.getInt("_LIMIT_"));
                        cachedRowSet.setFetchSize(pagination.getInt("_LIMIT_"));
                    }
                    if( pagination.has("_START_") && cachedRowSet.getPageSize()!=0){
                        cachedRowSet.populate(rs, pagination.getInt("_START_")+1);
                    }else{
                        cachedRowSet.populate(rs);
                    }

                    Object obj=null;
                    if (jsonType == CommonConstants.JSON_TYPE_MOBILE) {
                        obj = formatOtherData(cachedRowSet, rsmd, mMap);
                    } else if (jsonType == CommonConstants.JSON_TYPE_PLATEFORM) {
                        obj = formatPlatformData(cachedRowSet, rsmd);
                    } else if (jsonType == CommonConstants.JSON_DOWNLOAD_MOBILE) {
                        obj = formatOtherDownloadData(cachedRowSet, rsmd);
                    } else{
                        throw new Exception("Unknown Format");
                    }
                    return obj;
                }
            });
```

Output for this code is as follows

```
{"_START_":0,"_LIMIT_":10}
[http-bio-8081-exec-9] [ERROR] [SQLSERVER2307] ==> PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [SELECT "lj"."category_id" "category_id", "lj"."category_code" "category_code", "lj"."category_name" "category_name", "lj"."bz$_version_id" "bz$_version_id_5688" FROM "trn_375_category2" "lj"]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; The requested operation is not supported on forward only result sets.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The requested operation is not supported on forward only result sets.
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [SELECT "lj"."category_id" "category_id", "lj"."category_code" "category_code", "lj"."category_name" "category_name", "lj"."bz$_version_id" "bz$_version_id_5688" FROM "trn_375_category2" "lj"]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; The requested operation is not supported on forward only result sets.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The requested operation is not supported on forward only result sets.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:660)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:695)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:722)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:154)
    at com.buzzor.api.dao.impl.CommonQueryCallDaoImpl.getListByUserSQLQuery(CommonQueryCallDaoImpl.java:118)
    at com.buzzor.api.service.impl.CommonQueryCallServiceImpl.executeQuery(CommonQueryCallServiceImpl.java:182)
    at com.buzzor.api.service.impl.CommonUrlCallServiceImpl.getActualData(CommonUrlCallServiceImpl.java:490)
    at com.buzzor.api.service.impl.CommonUrlCallServiceImpl.getDataNOTrans(CommonUrlCallServiceImpl.java:609)
    at com.buzzor.api.service.impl.CommonUrlCallServiceImpl.getData(CommonUrlCallServiceImpl.java:306)
    at com.buzzor.api.service.impl.APIHandlerServiceImpl.callAPI(APIHandlerServiceImpl.java:105)
    at com.buzzor.portal.biz.impl.CommonGridServiceImpl.callAPI(CommonGridServiceImpl.java:851)
    at com.buzzor.portal.biz.impl.CommonGridServiceImpl.organizeData(CommonGridServiceImpl.java:797)
    at com.buzzor.portal.biz.impl.CommonGridServiceImpl.getReportQuery(CommonGridServiceImpl.java:714)
    at com.buzzor.portal.biz.impl.CommonGridServiceImpl.getReportData(CommonGridServiceImpl.java:161)
    at com.buzzor.portal.action.CommonGridAction.getData(CommonGridAction.java:309)
    at com.buzzor.portal.action.CommonGridAction.getGridData(CommonGridAction.java:474)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.buzzor.portal.security.RequestFilterSessionValidator.doFilterInternal(RequestFilterSessionValidator.java:46)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter.doFilter(RequestDumperFilter.java:203)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The requested operation is not supported on forward only result sets.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.throwNotScrollable(SQLServerResultSet.java:402)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.verifyResultSetIsScrollable(SQLServerResultSet.java:425)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.absolute(SQLServerResultSet.java:1564)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.absolute(DelegatingResultSet.java:335)
    at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.populate(CachedRowSetImpl.java:7255)
    at com.buzzor.api.dao.impl.CommonQueryCallDaoImpl$2.extractData(CommonQueryCallDaoImpl.java:128)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:708)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:644)
    ... 92 more
```

this same code works perfectly in mysql
but when i connect to sqlserver database it gives error while populating resultset

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get row count of a resultset in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886462/get-row-count-of-a-resultset-in-java)

Comment: no thats not duplicate for that i know that i have to set `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` but i dont have connection object available i am using `namedParameterJdbcTemplate`

Comment: Ah ok. At first glance it seems to deal with the same problem. But maybe it will push you in the right direction.