# Getting the count of the resultset values

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset, record-count

I need your assistant and help in getting the count of the values which are available in the `resultset`. The `resultset` is having 22 records and in the below code, it is printing the count starting from 1 to 23. Is there any way to get the total no. of records as 22 (one value only) or by subtracting the last value from the first value?

My code is below:

```
while (rs.next())
        {

        count=0;
        name1=rs.getString("name");  
                    out.println(rs.getRow());

                 }
```

I tried to use `rs.first()` and `rs.last()` and it produced the below error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Invalid operation for forward only resultset :
>   first

I tried to add the arguments to the `createstatement`, but the same exception is there:

```
 conn.createStatement(rs.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, rs.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

> java.sql.SQLException: Invalid operation for forward only resultset :
>   last

Please help me in the above issue.

Comment: there is a function already for it. rs.getRow(). I'm not sure, but similar.

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886462/get-row-count-of-a-resultset-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int rowcount = 0;
if (rs.last()) {
  rowcount = rs.getRow();
  rs.beforeFirst(); 
}
```

**EDIT:**

You need to change the statement of your query like this so that you can use the `rs.last()`

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(rs.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Your query");
```

Check [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

Comment: why not resultSet.getRow()?

Comment: @Nabin:- Thats what I used ;)

Comment: i mean, why not just that?

Comment: @Nabin:- You can but it is a good practice to use it like this!

Comment: It didn't solve the issue, I got the this error: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid operation for forward only resultset : last

Comment: @R.T. Please explain the issue mentioned by user3407440

Comment: @user3407440:- ResultSet.last() and other "absolutely-indexed" query operations are only available when the result set is scrollable. You need to change the Statement of your query like this: `Statement stmt = con.createStatement(
    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE
);`

Comment: @Nabin:- Hope that helps! :)

Comment: @R.T I got this error:cannot resolve symbol symbol : method createStatement (int) location: interface java.sql.Connection st1 = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE);

Comment: @user3407440 the [`createStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createStatement(int,%20int)) call takes at least two arguments see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createStatement(int,%20int))

`conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet. ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);`

Comment: @Beggs I got the exception: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid operation for forward only resultset : last

Comment: @user3407440 did you change your code from the default conn.createStatement() to the code above?  And which database and driver are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL's `count(*)`

```
  try{
      Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
      String selectquery = "select count(*) from YourTable";
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(selectquery);
      rs.next();          
      System.out.println("Amount of rows :" + rs.getInt(1));
    }
```

If you wanna count rows based on "name", then

```
try{
          Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
          String selectquery = "select count(name) from YourTable";
          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(selectquery);
          rs.next();          
          System.out.println("Amount of rows :" + rs.getInt(1));
        }
```

Comment: I am trying not to change the query as it is a complex query with more than 10 fields

Comment: In my solution you don't have to use `while (rs.next()) { .. }`, that's not even complex.

Comment: The problem is that I am using a dynamic query and it should display the count based on the name. This will not help

Comment: @user3407440, see edit above.