# requested operation is not supported on forward only Hibernate JEE

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a query that works fine but when i want to visit the second page of the results i get this exception:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException:The requested operation is not supported on forward only result sets 
Caused by : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The requested operation is not supported on forward only result sets
```

Here is my code

```
logger.info("Reqï¿½ete de recherche avancï¿½e des contrats: " + requete.toString());
   Query query = genericDAO.createQuery(requete.toString());
   setDateParameters(query, rechercheContratBean);
    return HibernatePage.getHibernatePageInstance(query, rechercheContratBean.getPageNumber(), rechercheContratBean.getObjectsPerPage());
```

My getHibernatePageInstance()

```
protected static HibernatePage getHibernatePageInstance(Query query, int pageNumber, int pageSize) {
    HibernatePage sp = new HibernatePage(pageNumber, pageSize);
    try {
        sp.scrollableResults = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
        sp.totalElements = sp.calculateTotalElementsByList(query);
        sp.determineElements(query);
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (log.isErrorEnabled())
                log.error("Failed to create ScrollPage by getScrollPageInstanceWithTotalByQuery: " + e.getMessage());
          throw e;
        }
    return sp;
}
```

with determineElement(query)

```
private void determineElements(Query query) throws HibernateException {

    if (Integer.MAX_VALUE == this.pageNumber)
          this.pageNumber = (getTotalNumberOfElements() / this.pageSize);

   elements = query.setFirstResult((this.pageNumber * this.pageSize)-this.pageSize).setMaxResults(this.pageSize + 1).list();
      }
```

I'm using `hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect`

Her is the stacktrace

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: The requested operation is not supported on forward only result sets 
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.java:108)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.absolute(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.advance(Loader.java:1651)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1982)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2463)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2449)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2279)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2274)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1115)
        at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
        at ma.softwork.commons.dao.impl.HibernatePage.determineElements(HibernatePage.java:205)
        at ma.softwork.commons.dao.impl.HibernatePage.getScrollPageInstanceWithTotalByList(HibernatePage.java:180)
        at ma.softwork.commons.dao.impl.HibernatePage.getHibernatePageInstance(HibernatePage.java:127)
        at ma.softwork.commons.dao.impl.HibernatePage.getHibernatePageInstance(HibernatePage.java:116)
        at ma.softwork.dao.impl.QueryBuilderFactory.rechercheContratsPagination(QueryBuilderFactory.java:332)
        at ma.per.service.contrat.ContratService.rechercheContratsPagination(ContratService.java:250)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Am i missing something ?

Comment: please verify <property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_scrollable_resultset" value="true"/> in persistence.xml

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but i already have it

Comment: [issue related to your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886462/how-to-get-row-count-using-resultset-in-java) Visit the link

Comment: I'm already using `stmt = getConnection().prepareStatement(query,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);` but it doesn't work :(